# javascript prototype chain incorrect

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypejs, prototype

Here is my code:

```
function A()
{
    this.prop = "A";
    this.propName = this.getProp() + 'name';
}
A.prototype.getProp = function(){return this.prop;}
A.prototype.getPropName = function(){return this.propName;}

function B()
{
    this.prop = "B";
}
B.prototype = new A();

var b = new B();
console.log(b.getPropName());
```

The output is:

```
Aname
```

But I hope want this:

```
Bname
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

thank you,I got the reason.

B never have a ownProperty named 'propName',so it use the 'propName' from A, it initialized in 'new A', after this it never change.

I can fix it by:

```
redefine the getter to function(){return this.prop + 'name';}
re-initilize in B
later initilize, keep the propName field, but default to null, the getter become to 
function(){return this.propName||(this.propName = this.prop + 'name')}
```

I'd like to use the last one.

Thank you again.

Comment: You're not setting `this.propName` in `B()`. Add this line to the top of your `B()` function: `A.call(this)`.

Comment: As far as  your code is concerned, B.propname is going to be the same as A.propname as you haven't changed it after building the prototype.

Comment: Why not generate `propName` in `getPropName`? That would also solve your problem.

Comment: I was incorrect about `A.call(this)`. You're sort of combining the behaviors of the constructors. The way you have it, you'll need to mimic the behavior of `A` in `B`. Or separate them, and set the prop by passing an argument.